# Как привязать программу с базой данных SQL?

Tags: c#, база-данных, c++

Я вот умею создавать на SQL БД, столбцы (начальный уровень). А теперь хочу узнать, как мне привязать созданную программу с БД? Просто тупо хочу поставить 2 текстбокса, писать туда и сохранить в созданной БД, чтобы при повторном включении программы, она вывели старые данные? Я поискал в гугле, не нашел. Наверное, плохо искал. Подтолкните меня, пожалуйста, к действиям.

Comment: Уточните в какой СУБД вы создавали базу - MySQL, MSSQL, Access, Oracle  и тд. Чтобы было от чего отталкиваться при ответе на ваш вопрос

Comment: @navi1893

- *(Это не ответ на ваш вопрос, скорее, практический совет)*

- Я бы на вашем месте освоил бы `NHibernate` или [`Entity Framework,`][2] чтобы не зависеть от используемой базы данных, да и вообще, понимание того, как работает какой-либо популярный `ORM-Framework` сильно упрощает последующую работу с данными и СУБД вообще.

- И да, ради интереса, по каким запросам вы производили поиск в гугле, пытаясь найти ответ на свой вопрос? :)

[1]: http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx
[2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот что я нашел

[Подключение к базе данных Microsoft Access](http://www.intuit.ru/department/se/msadonet/3/)

[ADO.NET Видео](http://rutube.ru/video/c341a47b46b98abed80fbc253e3851b4/)

Comment: а как к SQL подключиться??? @Мурад